How to create a custom column in power query? If it is not contain numeric
I am trying to add a custom column in power query. if the column (A) has 6 digit number, I would like to contain the values from the B column, otherwise should contain values from the C column.
in another word:
New Custom Column = IF( A contains 6 digit, B, C)

How to get around this ? many thanks in advance.


Assuming columns are named a b c then add column ... custom column ...
= try if Number.From([a])>99999 and Number.From([a])<1000000 then [b] else [c] otherwise [c]



Getting close now - have an  upvote ;)

What about 000000 or 000123?

Thank you! I assumed those don't count!  If you need those, use Davide's!

I agree that OP wasn't clear so it is open to interpretation



let a = Text.From([A]), 
b  = if Text.Length(a) = 6 and Text.Length(Text.Select(a,{"1".."9"})) = 6 then [B] else [C]
in  b

